# Apache2 по разному принимает запросы внутри сети и за её пределами, как это исправить?

Tags: linux, apache2, nextcloud

Имеется nextcloud-сервер, к которому пользователи обращаются внутри сети, и за её пределами. Внутри сети запрос на cloud.example.com возвращает страницу апача, а на нужную страницу попадаю переходя на cloud.example.com/nextcloud
За пределами сети, запрос cloud.example.com возвращает нужную страницу.

Comment: Вангую, в сети DNS сервер который на запрос по cloud.example.com выдает клиенту локальный адрес машины, на которой крутится апач